# Unable to open the page in chrome using android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, appium

I just written the simple script which will launch the chrome browser and navigate to google home page. But When I tried to execute my script It ran without any issue but It shows .data., in address bar instead of navigating to google home page as shown below:

[image]

Sample code:

```
private WebDriver driver;

 DesiredCapabilities desired = new DesiredCapabilities().android();
        desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,
                "Android Emulator");
        desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,
                "4.2.2");
        desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,
                "com.android.chrome");
        desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
                "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        // desired.setCapability("fullReset", "true");
        URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, desired);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Can somebody help me out.

Comment: please share your written script

Comment: Screenshots are not sufficient. Show the actual code and error messages or results. Please read [mcve].

Comment: You can edit your Question to add additional Infos.

Comment: Please [edit] the code into the question.

Comment: where is your navigating part .. Driver.get where is it . I cant see it. The driver initialization is correct . Data is ok. It has to know that it has to go the google.com right ?

Comment: Yes It will navigate to google.com. pls find the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been fixed this issue. Its because of using Incompatible version of chrome driver,and chrome apk file.

Its working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

this is missing in your code. How will it go. It has created the driver correctly. But you have to tell him where to go. you can get your normal home page,( if that's what you are looking for ) when you are opening a web driver in a temporary profile. If you want to open a particular browser profile you have to tell it to open that profile using the flag --user-data-dir while creating the chromedirver.

And yes the code that you have provided can never open your browser. It has incorrect capabilities.

Comment: It will be a part of @BeforeClass. I just invoked get method in it. Also could you please explain me little bit about flag --user-data-dir? like do I need to specify the apk file location in capabilities?

Comment: @SKumar SO what is the probelm now it is not going to google.com ? . Is it executing that line ?

Comment: It executed fine but It's not navigated to google page. only shows the image I posted here. url address shows .data instead of google.com

Comment: I still dont understand how without passing browser in capability you are able to create a session of the browser. Last time i had checked you had to pass the browser name in capability like this capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. I just posted the wrong code and that was used to open apk which is installed in emulator(Calculator). Pls find the updated code.

Comment: OK. Now the code looks ok except the fact that i dont think you need to give app package and app activity now. Can you remove them and try. And one more thing., is there any error in the appium server logs .

Comment: The appium server logs that you have given doesnt show that driver.get is performed. Which is a little surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the modified code as shown below.

```
public static AppiumDriver driver = null;

@BeforeSuite
public static void driverInitalize() throws Exception {
try {

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "a69fd414");
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

You have to use the capability `BROWSER_NAME` to specify that the test case is a web application. You should not use the app activity and app package capabilities for web applications.

You can view more detailed code/configs on Appium mobile web application automation from [here](https://debugger89.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/troubleshooting-appium-web-application-automation-in-android/)